# div content not staying within outer fixed div

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I have a div/modal with fixed position that contains a modal-header, modal-body, and modal-footer, and when I reduce the height (to about 650px or below), the modal-body content and modal-footer don't stay within the fixed div/modal and start to move out of the viewport. How can I ensure that the modal-body and modal-footer stay completely within the modal-content?

```css
.modal-header {
  font-size: 18px;
}

.details {
  width: 600px;
  min-height: 500px;
  background-color: #fff;
  position: fixed;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 15px #888;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -350px;
  margin-left: -300px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  z-index:1002;
}

.description {
  padding: 25px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  max-height: 600px;
}
@media (max-width: 620px) {
    .details {
      width: 96vw;
      left: 0%;
      margin-left: 0px;
    }
}

@media (max-height: 710px) {
    .details {
      height: 100vh;
      margin-top: 0px;
      top: 0%;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="details modal-content" style="display: block">
    <div class="modal-header">Modal Title
        <button type="button" class="close">&times;</button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body description">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus non ex lacus. Sed porta nibh ac scelerisque consectetur. Praesent efficitur non massa et finibus. Donec ullamcorper nisl at arcu tempor, nec placerat ante finibus. In eu diam quis magna
        tincidunt pretium a id elit. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Sed ut eros congue, molestie nibh id, finibus risus. In ut pellentesque quam. Morbi consectetur orci in quam luctus, id
        porttitor eros vulputate. Ut at nisl nec sem dapibus vestibulum in id ex. In fermentum eget nunc sit amet blandit. Morbi volutpat, nunc eu tincidunt accumsan, ligula sapien aliquam elit, at laoreet quam libero vitae diam. Mauris feugiat malesuada
        tellus eu gravida. Fusce posuere ligula sed lorem condimentum mattis. Ut pretium vel orci vitae tempor. Ut imperdiet sit amet lacus vel dignissim. Mauris nec euismod ipsum, et porttitor ipsum. Etiam consequat, libero at elementum rutrum, neque
        mauris pharetra tellus, ac volutpat mi nulla eu velit. Integer eu massa suscipit, pharetra mauris ac, luctus arcu. Duis vel blandit nibh, et finibus sem. Nam nec neque nulla. In a congue magna. Nunc varius pulvinar mollis. Pellentesque nulla diam,
        tristique nec vestibulum sit amet, efficitur sit amet mauris. Etiam sed tempus orci, a viverra risus. Mauris at posuere neque. Fusce laoreet, lectus a consectetur maximus, enim libero scelerisque lectus, eget dignissim lorem lorem vitae nisi.
        Nam purus purus, tempor vel placerat eu, laoreet et libero. Mauris eget posuere erat. Aliquam eu nulla eget enim accumsan ullamcorper. Morbi vitae odio a velit sollicitudin euismod. Phasellus eu libero arcu. Suspendisse volutpat ipsum eu nisi
        tempor, non pulvinar turpis sagittis. Vivamus nec viverra enim. Curabitur tempus ex interdum lectus venenatis, id pellentesque turpis interdum. Phasellus viverra est eu purus sagittis iaculis pellentesque at urna. In euismod elit id volutpat euismod.
        Maecenas tempor varius est, vitae lacinia massa sodales vitae. Suspendisse in lacus mi. Nulla eget urna in justo accumsan fringilla vitae id tellus. Donec semper sapien quis ex imperdiet, ut luctus mauris ullamcorper. Proin volutpat non metus
        sit amet tempor. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Etiam libero lectus, pretium at rutrum vitae, semper id massa. Aliquam imperdiet quam purus, eget sodales elit mattis sed. Aliquam imperdiet
        eros leo, malesuada mattis ex commodo quis.
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Close</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm also using bootstrap, so any default bootstrap styles are also applied.

Comment: Simplest solution would be to remove `height: 100vh` from `.modal-content.details` and `overflow: auto; max-height: 600px` from `.description` - that way whole modal will be scrollable when needed.

Answer (score 0):

Since the height of the modal content is inherited from the parent you have two options:

1- Reduce the height on your `.description`  to match the height of the parent.

2- Or move your `overflow-y: auto;` to `.details` instead of `.description`

Also you can use [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals) `modal-lg` on your dialog to extend the modal.